OneLogin redirect uri
I'm trying to follow this tutorial: Using OpenID Connect to Authenticate to an Android App
When I introduce the redirect URI like the tutorial: package_name://callback. But the oneLogin portal sends an Error:
Unknown URI scheme.
I want to redirect to specific fragment of my app, how could i do it?
I tried to create an intent filter:
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="package_name" />
</intent-filter>

My app is not published in Play Store and is a debug app. I think that I have to register specific web site for my app.
